# Moving Files as a Transaction in Python?

Tags: python, unix

I have a number of files that I want to move from one folder to another. If for any reason movement of one of those files fails, I want none of them moved. Basically, either all of the files should be moved, or none of them. I could write logic that approximates this myself, but before I do, is there a native Python or Unix way to do this? Figured the situation comes up often enough that a solution probably already exists and I just haven't heard of it.

Comment: `mv` already does this, althought it won't insure against power loss, you'll still have partial files left over there

Comment: Can you enumerate the reasons why a file couldn't be moved ? If you can enumerate them, you can check those reasons before moving your files and you'll be sure that all your files will be moved or none of them.

Comment: I can't enumerate them. I'm looking for something that will keep me safe in case a file can't be moved for some unexpected reason.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Python nor Unix has the notion of a transaction for actions on multiple files.

For movement with in a disk partition, the *mv* command will just update the directory entries using the same inodes so the file doesn't actually move (no risk of failure during the move).

For movement across disks, you could be a temporary directory on the target drive, copy all the files, and it it succeed just do a *mv* as described about, and finally clear the source.  This would provide some measure of protection.